# Find and Replace text and turn into hyperlinks

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

Is it possible to use the find and replace feature to find a word and attach a hyperlink to it? Below is an example that just replaces the text, any suggestions on how to format this to make it work. I'm trying to make it so AMD41 would be hyperlinked to example.com. What would the right code look like?

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content 
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="AMD41", Forward:=True 
If myRange.Find.Found = True Then myRange.Text = "www.example.com"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross-posted and answered in Microsoft Community. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-vba-find-and-replace-text-and-turn-into/4942c4bd-fae9-4595-afc0-d321ab6853e0 For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184 If you have posted elsewhere, please, please, please follow the directions on that page as to each post.

Comment: Please also review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You could have started your research by simply recording a macro to get the objects and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TextFindAndHyperlink()
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim WebAddress As String
    
    Set SearchRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    SearchText = "AMD41"
    WebAddress = "http://www.example.com/"

    With SearchRange.Find
        Do While .Execute(SearchText, , True, , , , True) = True
            With SearchRange
                .Hyperlinks.Add SearchRange, WebAddress
            End With
            SearchRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```